How to change source range of a Pivot table by using macro?
I get data incoming weekly into my dataset and I need to resize the range of it. I'm trying to write code that automates this task.

Problem 1: I didn't find a standard recommendation for this
Problem 2: the approach I tried returns: "time error execution '5'"

Option Explicit

Sub ListPivotsInfor()
'Update 20141112
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim St As Worksheet
    Dim NewSt As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
   
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each St In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Debug.Print St.Name
        For Each pt In St.PivotTables
                Debug.Print Worksheets("DADOS").Range("A6")
                'pt.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=, Version:=7)
                Dim ptbl As PivotTable: Set ptbl = pt
                ptbl.ChangePivotCache wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("DADOS").Range("A2:AD281"), Version:=7)
            Next
        Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

I'm expecting that code increase the range of the incoming data and update all pivot table and graphs of this workbook.

You can access PivotCaches via the workbook.
The SourceData should have a very specific format. See the function in the example below.
You can always code your pivot creation each time from scratch, but this is takes some rather complex coding but is more adaptable long-term.
For changing the data range you can do something like the following for example (not tested):
Function Address_Full_String$(ByRef Temp_Range As Range)
Address_Full_String$ = "'[" + CStr(Temp_Range.Worksheet.Parent.Name) + "]" + CStr(Temp_Range.Worksheet.Name) + "'!" + CStr(Temp_Range.Address(, , xlR1C1))
End Function

Sub modifyPivot()
Dim DataWS As Worksheet
Dim newRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'The worksheet where your data is - You can also address it by "name" instead of using 1
Set DataWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Get the last cell of your new data
Set newRange = DataWS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
'The pivotCahces index you want to change
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).SourceData = Address_Full_String$(newRange)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1).Refresh
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Format your dataset as a Table (ListObject).  Select a cell within the data and press Ctrl+t.  The Create Table dialog will display.  Make sure the "My table has headers" checkbox is checked, click OK.
Now your data is organized as a Table.  Tables automatically resize as data is added/removed.  They can also be set as your Pivot Table's datasource.  Since the Table resizes, all you have to do after your data refreshes is update the Pivot table.
